# Why does the check function does not working?

Tags: python

I need to program a game that called "4 in a row". every thing except of half of the check function works! in check function it is working only when the column is out of range. but, if the whole column is full- it is simply don't work. even if the top is not 0, matrix[0][col] always equals to 0.

I don't understand why matrix[0][col] always 0.

```
FIRST = 1
SECOND = 2
EMPTY = 0

matrix = []
for row in range(SIZE):
    row_to_add = []
    for col in range(SIZE):
        row_to_add.append(EMPTY)
    matrix.append(row_to_add)

for row in range(SIZE):
    for col in range(SIZE):
        print(matrix[row][col], end=" ")
    print()

def pboard(matrix):
    for row in range(SIZE):
        for col in range(SIZE):
            print(matrix[row][col], end=" ")
        print()



def function( who2):
    global col
    for i in range(SIZE):
        i+=1
        i*=-1
        if matrix[i][col]==0:
            matrix[i][col]= who2
            break


def check():
    global col
    global SIZE
    global booli
    global matrix

    while (col>10 or col<0 or matrix[0][col]):
        col=int(input("try again."))

    if col==-1:
        booli=False
    return False


def win(who2):
    global matrix
    count=0
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        count=0
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            if matrix[i][j]==who2:
                count+=1
            if count>=4:
                return "Win!!"
            if matrix[i][j]!=who2:
                count=0
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        count=0
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            if matrix[j][i]==who2:
                count+=1
            if count>=4:
                return "Win!!"
            if matrix[j][i]!=who2:
                count=0

col=int(input("enter the column: "))
booli=True
who=0
while col!=-1 :
    if who%2==0:
        check()
        if booli == False:
            break
        else:
            col -= 1

        function(FIRST)
        pboard(matrix)
        print(win(FIRST))
    elif who % 2 != 0:
        check()
        if booli==False:
            break
        else:
            col -= 1
        function( SECOND)
        pboard(matrix)
        print(win(SECOND))
    if win( FIRST)=="Win!!" or win(SECOND)=="Win!!":
        break
    who+=1
    col = int(input("enter the column: "))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your `check()` function, if the column is full, the function will keep asking for a new column input until it gets a column that's not full or until the user enters -1 to break the loop, but you're not updating the value of col inside the while loop, so the col value remains the same.

Also in your while loop, you subtract 1 from col before calling the `function()`

This should do what you want :

```
FIRST = 1
SECOND = 2
EMPTY = 0

SIZE = 6

matrix = []
for row in range(SIZE):
    row_to_add = []
    for col in range(SIZE):
        row_to_add.append(EMPTY)
    matrix.append(row_to_add)

def pboard(matrix):
    for row in range(SIZE):
        for col in range(SIZE):
            print(matrix[row][col], end=" ")
        print()

def function(who2):
    global col
    for i in range(SIZE):
        i+=1
        i*=-1
        if matrix[i][col]==0:
            matrix[i][col]= who2
            break

def check():
    global col
    global SIZE
    global booli
    global matrix

    while (col>SIZE or col<0 or matrix[0][col]):
        col=int(input("try again."))

    if col==-1:
        booli=False
    return False

def win(who2):
    global matrix
    count=0
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        count=0
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            if matrix[i][j]==who2:
                count+=1
            if count>=4:
                return "Win!!"
            if matrix[i][j]!=who2:
                count=0
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        count=0
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            if matrix[j][i]==who2:
                count+=1
            if count>=4:
                return "Win!!"
            if matrix[j][i]!=who2:
                count=0

col=int(input("enter the column: "))
booli=True
who=0
while col!=-1 :
    if who%2==0:
        check()
        if booli == False:
            break
        function(FIRST)
        pboard(matrix)
        print(win(FIRST))
    elif who % 2 != 0:
        check()
        if booli==False:
            break
        function(SECOND)
        pboard(matrix)
        print(win(SECOND))
    if win(FIRST)=="Win!!" or win(SECOND)=="Win!!":
        break
    who+=1
    col = int(input("enter the column: "))
```

Comment: You welcome :)) dont forget to accept the answer if it is all good for you